# Perturbing coefficients of a polynomial with simple real zeroes

Tags: polynomials, roots

So I have polynomials whose coefficients have been computed with a given accuracy. I know that the original polynomials have simple and real zeroes by construction. I also know an interval where the roots lie, i.e in [a,b].

Then I compute the roots of these perturbed polynomials with, let's say, the same accuracy. It is done with matlab which uses the companion matrix method.

Is there a way to provide a bound for how much the roots of the perturbed polynomial may differ from the original modulus?

I tried utilizing the fact that simple roots imply that the eigenvector matrix of the companion matrix is the vandermonde matrix of the roots followed by Baur and Fike's theorem. However I found no theory developed for bounds on the condition number for the vandermonde matrix. Can something more specific be said since the roots also are real?

Maybe that method of attack is a dead end and the question should be left at:

Suppose we have a known polynomial q which is a pertubation of an unknown polynomial p with respect to the coefficients by no more than epsilon. Suppose furthermore that it is known that p has simple and real roots located in [a,b].
Suppose we then compute the roots of q. What can then be said about the location of p's roots. Can one form a bound expressing how much they may differ from q's roots?